# Get windows' titles using command line

Tags: command-line, xfce, window-title

Is it possible to get the titles of all the running GUI application windows via CLI? The titles which are also shown on the task bar buttons. For example:

- Firefox: cPanel X - Main
- Nautilus: File System - File Manager

I am using Linux Mint XFCE (17.3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use external tool such as for example `wmctrl`.

To list all running windows pass `-l` option to it. It is also possible to change title of specified application (short title with `-I`, long with `-N` or both with `-T`).

Run `man wmctrl` for more info.