# Linux how to get window title with just shell script?

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator, window, window-title

I cannot install any tools like screen or xproc on the box. I dont need to modify the title, I only need to find the window title name.

`echo -e "\033]0;[title]\07";` modifies the title I know. But I just want to know the existing title name.

Comment: does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122870/117549 do it for you?

Comment: or possibly https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274386/117549

Comment: my os does not recognize those as commands

Comment: `printf '\e[21t'` should cause your terminal to return its title in the form `\e]title\e\\ `. I'll try to wrap that in a script if they don't delete your question until then.

Comment: I tried the above and got the result below, this is definitely in the right direction, as I was not getting any output before. print "\033[21t" >$(tty)
IFS='' read -t 3 -r a output : ^[]l^[\

Comment: Hi Anyone who can help me with my question? I am still struggling with this thing, I know there is some command like print "\033[21t::\007". Please help if anyone knows the answer to it.

Comment: X Window name may be different what you see on the screen, am I wrong?

Comment: I smell a possible XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) here. What do you need it for? Isn't for example saving and restoring the title sufficient for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, but notice that the compatibility is pretty limited. See the notes below.

```
get_title(){(
        set -e
        ss=`stty -g`; trap 'exit 11' INT QUIT TERM; trap 'stty "$ss"' EXIT
        e=`printf '\033'`; st=`printf '\234'`; t=
        stty -echo -icanon min 0 time "${2:-2}"
        printf "${1:-\033[21t}" > "`tty`"
        while c=`dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null` && [ "$c" ]; do
                t="$t$c"
                case "$t" in
                $e*$e\\|$e*$st)
                        t=${t%$e\\}; t=${t%$st}; printf '%s\n' "${t#$e\][lL]}";
                        exit 0;;
                $e*);;
                *) break;;
                esac
        done
        printf %s "$t"; exit 1
)}
```

Example:

```
$ get_title
$ title=`get_title`
```

Or, if your script's stdin is not the terminal:

```
$ title=`get_title </dev/tty`
```

The `stty` + `dd` kludge tries to make sure that the script won't just block if the terminal doesn't report anything in response to the `\e[21t` escape. This (or a better) approach could be also used with other control sequences (eg. to get the cursor position).

**Notes:**

Since the `\e[21t` escape is considered "insecure", extra configuration is needed in order to make it work:

For `xterm`: `echo '*.vt100.allowWindowOps: true' | xrdb -override`

For `urxvt`: `echo 'Rxvt.insecure: true' | xrdb -override`

It will **not work at all** in vte-based terminals like `gnome-terminal`, `mate-terminal`, `xfce4-terminal`, etc, since they report either a [fake](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/blob/a235384892c617c961cd1c9131227f8b1363fa22/src/vteseq.cc#L3063) ("Terminal") or [empty](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/blob/417b9958a135ca1cb3ccf6252d3ce0dbcf7ded35/src/vteseq.cc#L8500) title in response.

`mlterm` doesn't need anything special, but it will crash (!) if the title wasn't set before with `\e]2;TITLE\a` (that bug was [fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/mlterm/mailman/message/36474921/) in the current sources).

`screen` will report its own window title (the one that was set with the `-t` option or the <kbd>C-a A</kbd> command, not the title of the window it's running in.

It's blocked and not supported in `tmux`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: @Bootham_Deyyam , since it appears that this answer works for you, you should mark it as correct (click the check mark under the votes). In my opinion, you should also up-vote it. This is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

For example, getting the title of `konsole` window current interactive `bash` instance is running in:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

get_title() {

    local pid=$$
    local pids=`pstree -lpsT $pid | tr '-' '\n' | tac | xargs | grep -oE '[0-9]+'`

    for pid in $pids
    do
        local wid=`xdotool search --pid $pid`
        if [ ! -z "${wid}" ]
        then
            echo `xdotool getwindowname $wid`
            exit
        fi
    done
}

get_title
```